# Why do we choose $\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$ instead of $\frac{1}{1-z} = z + z^2 +\cdots$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

In Laurent series, we have the following

$$\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + \dots + z^n, \qquad 0 < \mid z\mid < 1, \quad n \rightarrow \infty$$

However, $\frac{1}{1-z} = z + z^2 + z^3 ...  +z^n (0 < \mid z\mid < 1, n \rightarrow \infty)$
also works.

Since geometric series can be written

$$z + z^2 + z^3 ... + z^n = \frac{1 - z^n}{1-z}  (0 < \mid z\mid < 1, n \rightarrow \infty)$$
$$z + z^2 + z^3 ... + z^n = \frac{1}{1-z} (0 < \mid z\mid < 1, n \rightarrow \infty,\mid z^n \mid \rightarrow 0) $$

My question is: why do we not use $$\frac{1}{1-z} = z + z^2 + z^3... + z^n (0 < \mid z\mid < 1, n \rightarrow \infty) ?$$

Comment: What? It is $\frac{z}{1-z}=z+z^2+z^3+\ldots$

Comment: What about value at $z=0$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro What do you mean?

Comment: @Yalikesifulei $$\frac{1} {1-0} =1$$

Comment: @kile so, $1 = 0$?

Comment: @Yalikesifulei I just modified it.

Comment: I mean that the sum you write equals $\frac{z}{1-z}$, not $\frac{1}{1-z}$. (I am not the downvoter. As usual I disagree with downvotes that do not come with a comment).

Comment: The equation following "Since" is simply wrong.

Comment: @TonyK Where did I misunderstand this?

Comment: Actually $$z+z^2+\cdots+z^n=\frac{z-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$ for $z\ne1$.

Comment: @bof Thank you for explanation

Comment: Keep dividing 1 by $1-z$ ordinarily you will get $1+z+z^2+z^3+......$ as the 
quotient.

Comment: I actually UPvoted. Sure, this was a basic mistake but this is how we learn

Comment: Sort of a long shot, but are you thinking of the Laurent series _outside_ the closed unit disk, where by setting $w = 1/z$ we have$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1/z}{1/z-1}=-\frac{w}{1-w}=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}w^k?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation you wrote is obviously a MISTAKE:
$$z+z^2+z^3..+z^n=\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}.$$
Why?

Put $z=0$. Then:

$$0+0+0...+0=\frac{1-0^n}{1-0}\implies 0=1.$$